# Moving around GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create MOB AI using rigidbody. I want to make the mob (GameObject) walk around the world using

```
mobrigid.AddForce((((goal - transform.position).normalized)*speed * Time.deltaTime));
```

(goal is a random place around mob).

here is where it gets complicated, some mobs fly up in the air at extreme speeds while others move normaly at slow speed. (And yes, I do make sure the goal.Y is a place on the ground and not air). I tried fixing it by changing the drag, but that leads to mobs walking on air and not falling with gravity.

I'm really lost, can't figure out how do I simply move a gameobject around with rigidbody without getting this odd behavior.

Logs of mobs (with Y of goal changed to 0):
[image]

Edit:
 Image of the mob:
[image]

my movement logic:

```
   case MOBTYPE.EARTHMOB:
            switch (currentstatus)
            {
                case MOBSTATUS.STANDING:

                        if (mobrigid.IsSleeping())
                        {
                            mobrigid.WakeUp();
                        }   



                        goal = this.transform.position;
                            goal.x = Random.Range(goal.x - 150, goal.x + 150);
                            goal.z = Random.Range(goal.z -150, goal.z + 150);
                    goal.y = 0;

                                    currentstatus = MOBSTATUS.WALKING;

                 //   Debug.Log("Transform:"+this.transform.position+ "Goal:" + goal+ "goal-transform:" + (goal - transform.position));

                    break;
                case MOBSTATUS.WALKING:
                    if (Random.Range(1, 100) == 5)
                    {
                        currentstatus = MOBSTATUS.STANDING;
                    }
                    if (mobrigid.IsSleeping())
                    {
                        mobrigid.WakeUp();
                    }
                    mobrigid.AddForce((((goal - transform.position).normalized) * 10000 * Time.deltaTime));
                    // transform.LookAt(goal);
                    var distance = Vector3.Distance(goal, gameObject.transform.position);
                    if (distance <=5)
                    {

                        currentstatus = MOBSTATUS.STANDING;

                    }

                    break;
            }
            break;
```

Terrain Image:
[image]

Comment: `goal is a random place` are you using random function to get place ? Try fixing z coordinates with hardcoded value say '0' and only generate random x and y something like vector(x, y, 0), log the difference vector `goal - transform.position` and do not try to `fix` anything or you will lose the track. Try to find the root cause.

Comment: @NeverHopeless why x, and y? shouldn't I get x and z? I get the goal like that: goal=MOB position, then x=random(mob.x-15,mob.x+10); same for z. I will log goal-transform.position and update and Y is the given position max height at the terrain

Comment: You are right it should be x and z. When you say `goal=MOB position` do you later fix it something like goal = vector(random(mob.x-15,mob.x+10), 0, random(mob.z-15,mob.z+10). As per my understanding, Y coordinate should be zero here instead of `mob.y` or you will experience a difference in y-axis as well during `goal - transform.position`. Please give this a try.

Comment: If your force is added toward the floor, your rigidbody may be thrown in the air if he overlaps the floor with too much force. Be sure that the force added is parallel to the floor.

Comment: @NeverHopeless I edited logs, didn't know that Greg thanks, what should I do then to avoid that?

Comment: and what happens if you set `goal-transform.y` to zero ?

Comment: Okay. @NeverHopeless I did that and they kept moving, turns out the bug was with : transform.LookAt(goal);, I wanted them to look at target but for some reason it also moved them on the map. Removing that line fixed them moving up at extreme speeds however now they move a little and stop moving. I tried to set Y back to map height but then they start floating around.

Comment: @Programmer I never stop moving them. They reach goal and I calculate their new goal position for further moving. I will update now the thread with image of the mob and more code

Comment: @Programmer edited, and yes. when mob reaches goal it generates a new position around mob. That, or 1\100 chance for it to stop and look for new position.

Comment: Yes, its a random generated terrain similar to Minecraft. Its made of a mesh ill edit now a bigger image

Comment: Everything I asked were really important in order to help. Is this a real terrai created with the `Terrain` and `TerrainData` class or is it just bunch of generated meshes with colliders?

Comment: @Programmer meshes with colliders, its not actual terrain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Rigidbody.AddForce` function is used to add force to an Object along a direction. Since you have a position you need to move a `Rigidbody` to, you have to use the `Rigidbody.MovePosition` function. You may also want to mark the Rigidbody as kinematic.

A simple coroutine function to move a Rigidbody object to specific position:

```
IEnumerator MoveRigidbody(Rigidbody rb, Vector3 destination, float speed = 50f)
{
    const float destThreshold = 0.4f;

    while (true)
    {
        Vector3 direction = (destination - rb.position).normalized;
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + direction * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        float dist = Vector3.Distance(rb.position, destination);

        //Exit function if we are very close to the destination
        if (dist <= destThreshold)
            yield break;

        yield return null;
        //yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();
    }
}
```

It better to call this from another coorutine funtion so that you can yield or wait for it to finish then do other task like generating the random postion again and moving the Rigidbody there.

You want to generate new postion then move the `Rigidbody` there, this is an example of how to call the function above:

```
IEnumerator StartMoveMent()
{
    Rigidbody targetRb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    while (true)
    {
        //Generate random position
        Vector3 destination = new Vector3();
        destination.y = 0;
        destination.x = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 50);
        destination.z = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 50);

        //Move and wait until the movement is done
        yield return StartCoroutine(MoveRigidbody(targetRb, destination, 30f));
    }
}
```

And to start the `StartMoveMent` function:

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(StartMoveMent());
}
```

---

While what I said above should work, I do recommend you use Unity's built in pathfinding system. [Here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/s/navigation?_ga=2.94883868.1018465887.1532227326-753344725.1531910395) is a tutorial for that. It simplifies finding paths to follow towards a destination with [`NavMesh`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/nav-BuildingNavMesh.html) which can also be [`baked during run-time`](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/navigation/baking-navmesh-runtime).

Comment: Thanks for you answer! before I implement it, because my code is very different and uses different switches in the update function instead of IEnumrators.. I want to ask if there will be performance differences if I do what you said inside update instead of IENumerator?

Comment: Not really. IEnumerator gives you advantage of executing code sequentially. You can still do it in the Update function if you wish